# Is it possible to create custom hotkey binding commands in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For example, I'd like to bind Ctr+H to the keyboard Home key or Ctr+l Ctr+b to the keyboard [ key. I've found the Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard options but the commands, while very extensive, are still limited. I'm hoping this is extensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to handle custom key bindings. You need to write your own VS Extension. However, there is some really great documentation out there on how to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd885474.aspx - A MSDN Walkthrough specific to key bindings.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2009/06/01/visual-studio-2010-sdk-beta-1-is-now-live.aspx - A general tutorial on VS Extensions

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2680 - The VS2010 sdk.